# convert marginStart to marginLeft

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have to work on an existing project. The minimum support on this project was at `API Level 17`, but due to some changes I have to convert it to support on `API Level 16`. The project is really big (consist of millions of lines of code).
So the problem is it have a lot of layout_marginStart and layout_marginEnd attributes. These attributes needs to go with layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight. [More info on this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

How can I add left and right attributes along with start and left (We still have to support API Level 17, so can't remove start and end)? I do not want to use find and replace, because it changes a lot of existing documentation and is really unpredictable in project of this size. I am looking for a gradle task which can add the attribute at runtime or can permanently add or remove these extra attributes.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of it.

Comment: I think, We need to go screen by screen and change their layouts for RTL support.